# For() loop not doing anything in the first loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am doing the 3rd project of TOP (The Odin Project) which consists of creating a simple rock paper scissors game with no GUI for the moment, just on the console. This is a pseudo-code for the loop I want to make:

prompt user for number of rounds, assign to variable rounds
start counter (i) at 0 and for the values of i up to (not including) the number of rounds, execute the following code:

I have no problem with this code, it used to work perfectly using the while loop instead of the for loop, so I guess I must have done something incorrectly.

Here is the code I've written:

```
let rounds = prompt("How many rounds do you want to play?")

for (let i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
    let playerMove = convertToNumber(promptPlayer())
    let computerMove = computerPlay()
    if (computerMove > playerMove) {
        if (computerMove === 2 && playerMove === 0) {
            console.log(`You won! ${convertToItem(playerMove)} beats ${convertToItem(computerMove)}.`)
        } else {
            console.log(`You lost! ${convertToItem(computerMove)} beats ${convertToItem(playerMove)}.`)
        }
    } else if (playerMove > computerMove) {
        if (computerMove === 0 && playerMove === 2) {
            console.log(`You lost! ${convertToItem(computerMove)} beats ${convertToItem(playerMove)}.`)
        } else {
            console.log(`You won! ${convertToItem(playerMove)} beats ${convertToItem(computerMove)}.`)
        }
    } else if (playerMove) {
    console.log("Ties!")
    }
}
```

And this is a detailed explanation of the page's behaviour: If I enter 5, it will prompt me for rock, paper or scissors 5 times, and each one, except for the first one (that is the problem) is logged in the console. I have no clue why the first one is omitted.

I'm not sure weather I provided enough information, if not, I will send the whole code (6 lines, not much). The rest of the code are just function declarations which I did not alter when I changed the while loop to a for loop.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I saw many comments were highlighting the insufficient code, so here is the complete code I wrote:

```
function computerPlay() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
}

function convertToItem(num) {
    switch (num) {
        case 0:
            return "rock";
        case 1:
            return "paper";
        case 2:
            return "scissors";
    }
}

function convertToNumber(item) {
    switch (item) {
        case "rock":
            return 0;
        case "paper":
            return 1;
        case "scissors":
            return 2;
    }
}

function promptPlayer() {
    let playerMove = prompt("Rock, Paper or Scissors?").toLowerCase()
    if (playerMove !== "rock" && playerMove !== "paper" && playerMove !== "scissors") {
        alert("Invalid answer! Try again.")
    } else {
        return playerMove
    } 
}

let rounds = prompt("How many rounds do you want to play?")

for (let i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
    let playerMove = convertToNumber(promptPlayer())
    let computerMove = computerPlay()
    if (computerMove > playerMove) {
        if (computerMove === 2 && playerMove === 0) {
            console.log(`You won! ${convertToItem(playerMove)} beats ${convertToItem(computerMove)}.`)
        } else {
            console.log(`You lost! ${convertToItem(computerMove)} beats ${convertToItem(playerMove)}.`)
        }
    } else if (playerMove > computerMove) {
        if (computerMove === 0 && playerMove === 2) {
            console.log(`You lost! ${convertToItem(computerMove)} beats ${convertToItem(playerMove)}.`)
        } else {
            console.log(`You won! ${convertToItem(playerMove)} beats ${convertToItem(computerMove)}.`)
        }
    } else if (playerMove) {
    console.log("Ties!")
    }
}
```

Comment: `else if (playerMove)` will not execute when `playerMove = 0`. Is that the problem, rather than "the first move"?

Comment: Aside from the erroneous`if (playerMove)` noted by @VLAZ the behavior you describe cannot be reproduced, because there is a lot missing dependencies.  Please modify the question to include a [mcve].  (Bets are on VLAZ being correct, since the code includes references to `playerMove` being 0)

Comment: @VLAZ I understand what you are saying. My intention with else if (playerMove) was to return false when no input was provided (empty string = false). Otherwise, it would be recorded as ties. Would else if (playerMove !== null) solve the problem? I'm not sure whether to choose null or undefined... Thank you! (The post have been editet to contain all the code necessary to be run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop does work. That's the reason you're getting 5 prompts. But your if-statements aren't always true, so sometimes it won't output something in the console. Especially the last one is a strange one. If everything else needs to be *Ties!* then just use the `else` instead of another `else if` (that might be false and won't display a message)

You're sample code is insufficient for a working example so i've made some changes below, but the loop is the same and the logic with if-statements (all thought I did change the order a bit so I didn't need nested if's).

```js
let rounds = prompt("How many rounds do you want to play?");

for (let i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
    let playerMove = Number( prompt("What your gonna do? Rock=0; Paper=1; Scissors=2;") ); // Expect a number 0, 1 or 2
    let computerMove = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) // random number 0, 1 or 2
    
    // if numbers from playerMove and computerMove are the same it's a tie
    if (playerMove === computerMove) {
        console.log("Ties!");
    } 
    // if player has Rock(0) and computer Paper(1) or player has Paper(1) and computer Scissors(2) you lose..
    // if player has Scissors(2) but computer has Rock(0) you lose as well
    else if (playerMove+1 === computerMove || playerMove-2 === computerMove) {
        console.log("You lost!");
        }
    // in all other cases you win
    else {
            console.log("You win!");
    }
    
    console.log("Played by player: "  + playerMove);
    console.log("Played by computer: " + computerMove);
}
```

Comment: I updated my post so that the code is now complete. I will review your suggestion and see if I can get it fixed tomorrow. Thanks!